# Having issues to printf numbers in this typedef struct algorithm

Tags: arrays, c, struct, printf, scanf

Im doing this struct to print the register of some people i want to register, saving in a array and printing but when i used float it was printing a memory dump and now the int numbers are becoming memory dump too

```
#include <stdio.h>

    typedef struct{
        int id_insc[20];
        char nome[50];
        char altura[10];
        int peso[8];
        char naturalidade[15];
        char estado[10];
    } Empregado;

main(){
    

    Empregado empregado[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("1. Digite o ID da inscricao\n");
    scanf("%d", empregado[i].id_insc);
    
    printf("2. Digite o nome do candidato(a)\n");
    scanf("%s", empregado[i].nome);
    
    printf("3. Digite a altura\n");
    scanf("%s", empregado[i].altura);
    
    printf("4. Digite o peso do candidato (sem casas decimais)\n");
    scanf("%d", empregado[i].peso);
    
    printf("5. Digite a naturalidade do candidato(a)\n");
    scanf("%s", empregado[i].naturalidade);

    printf("6. Digite o estado do candidato(a)\n");
    scanf("%s", empregado[i].estado);
    system("cls");
}

system("cls");

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf(" Id: %d\n Nome: %s\n Altura: %s\n Peso: %d\n Naturalidade: %s\n Estado: %s\n",
    empregado[i].id_insc, 
    empregado[i].nome,
    empregado[i].altura,
    empregado[i].peso,
    empregado[i].naturalidade,
    empregado[i].estado);
    printf("\n");

}
}
```

Id: 6487160
Nome: gustavo
Altura: 180
Peso: 6487300
Naturalidade: brasileiro
Estado: parana

the output is printing like this and i typed 11 and 60

Comment: Why do your clients have 20 ID numbers?  And 8 `peso` elements?  You need to review what you're doing with both those.

Answer (score 1):

For starters in this calls of scanf

```
printf("1. Digite o ID da inscricao\n");
scanf("%d", empregado[i].id_insc);

printf("4. Digite o peso do candidato (sem casas decimais)\n");
scanf("%d", empregado[i].peso);
```

you entered only the first elements of the data member arrays

```
int id_insc[20];
```

and

```
int peso[8];
```

That is these calls of scanf

```
scanf("%d", empregado[i].id_insc);
```

and

```
scanf("%d", empregado[i].peso);
```

are equivalent to

```
scanf("%d", &empregado[i].id_insc[0]);
```

and

```
scanf("%d", &empregado[i].peso[0] );
```

because arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements. You can not to enter all elements of an integer array using only one format string `"%d"`.

If you want to enter values for all elements of the arrays you need to use one more for loop.

To output them in the call of `printf` you have to specify these arguments

```
empregado[i].id_insc[0],
```

and

```
empregado[i].peso[0],
```

instead of

```
empregado[i].id_insc,
```

and

```
empregado[i].peso,
```

Again you can not use one conversion specifier `%d` to output all elements of an integer array. You need to use additional loops. The conversion specifier `%d` used in a call of `printf` expects a scalar object of the type `int`.